# Visualforce: get first word in string?

Tags: visualforce

How can I retrieve the first word in a string in Salesforce? Something like this (this is Ruby, but you get the idea):

```
"John Smith".split(' ').first
-> "John"
```

Any help? Thanks.

**Update**

Great suggestions, but they're not exactly succinct. Is the best way really to create another field for the sObject and store it in there?

**Update two**

Here's the code:

```
Hi {!Lead.FirstName},
<br><br>
Congratulations on taking Step 1 today with {!LEFT(Lead.Picklist_Value__c, IF(FIND(Lead.Picklist_Value__c, " ") = 0, LEN(Lead.Picklist_Value__c), FIND(Lead.Picklist_Value__c, " ")))}!
<br><br>
Best Wishes,
<br>
{!Lead.Picklist_Value__c}
```

The first returns blank, the second returns the whole name. I've tried all the suggestions in this post, too.

Comment: do you need to do this on the VF page itself with a formula expression or in the controller?

Comment: Preferably in the VF page since it's an email template and without its own controller.

Comment: There are 3 solutions suitable for email templates, and they are working for me. Could you post your code? Are you sure that field level security is fine?

Comment: Updated. Should be all good?

Comment: @CD-RUM unfortunately, when your field is picklist type, those doesn't work, (no idea why). Probably, fastest solution would be custom formula creation.

Answer (score 5):

In apex, you could use the [String.substringBefore(string)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_substringBefore) method. Essentially the same behavior as the `.split(' ')[0]` mechanism but `substringBefore` uses a string instead of a RegEx pattern.

```
String s1 = 'John Smith';
String s2 = s1.substringBefore(' ');
System.assertEquals('John', s2);
```

Comment: While it doesn't matter much for small strings, split actually accepts a pattern instead of a literal string, thus adding some processing overhead.

Answer (score 4):

In Visualforce, you can use normal formula syntax:

```
{!LEFT(lead.Picklist_Value__c, FIND(' ', lead.Picklist_Value__c))}
```

Comment: Returns blank, too. And the field definitely has words in it. Do I need to convert it to a string or something first? All these attempts are returning blank in the email template.

Comment: Love the moniker. Anyways, I actually did test this before posting. Possibly you're referencing the wrong object? Might help if you copy and paste your template in.

Comment: Ha, thanks. I've posted a bit of it in update two above.

Comment: aak - how could I have forgotten about `LEFT(..)` . I use it all the time

Comment: @CD-RUM Your find parameters are reversed. The space has to come first.

Answer (score 3):

Considered next scenarios:

**Apex**

**Split** method in salesforce returns array of string, so you can just use:

> 'John Smith'.split(' ').get(0)

or

> 'John Smith'.split(' ')[0]

**Visualforce or formula**

You can use combination of **LEFT**, **LEN** and **FIND** formulas to find first separator in variable if that exists
For example, if separator is space and variable is **text__c**.
so, formula would look like next:

> {!LEFT(text__c,IF(FIND(" ",text__c) = 0, LEN(text__c), FIND(" ",text__c
>   )))}

Literally that mean pick left N character of string, where N is position of first space if spaces are in string or N is length of string if string doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: `{!lead.Picklist_Value__c.split(' ')[0]}` returns blank?

Comment: also, check for  pickList_value__c == null before split

Answer (score 1):

To get the first word out of a field value in a VF email template without a corresponding formula field on the sobject or a VF component controller....

Use a formula expression.

Here, the merge field is `relatedTo.foo__c`

```
{!IF(ISBLANK(relatedTo.foo__c),NULL, /* null field displays as null */
  IF(NOT(CONTAINS(relatedTo.foo__c,' ')),relatedTo.foo__c, /* no blank, use whole fld */
  MID(relatedTo.foo__c, 1, FIND(' ', relatedTo.foo__c)) /* locate blank and substr to it (inclusive) */
))}
```

Your use case may need to use `recipient.foo__c` if that is the field you are referencing is who is getting the email.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question pertained to picklists, and no solutions here work in VF for picklists, I'll post my solution. It was to use @kurunve's `split(' ')[0]` method in an Apex trigger and fill out another custom field like so:

```
trigger ValueLead on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    for (Lead lead: Trigger.new) {
        if (lead.Picklist_Value__c != null) {
            lead.Picklist_Value_First_Name__c = lead.Picklist_Value__c.split(' ')[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Not ideal but it works.

Comment: Why did the `FIND( )` method not work? Did you correct the problem you have in your **Update 2** edit of your question with the parameters being in the wrong order as noted above and still not have success?